# Do I need to remove event listeners from window object before the window is closed?

Tags: javascript

I know that event listeners can cause memory leaks if they're not removed from an unused DOM element. My question is, does that also apply to the window object? I have an event listener for "storage" events, I need it bound for as long as the tab is open. Does the browser clear event listeners when the window (tab) is closed, or is that a memory leak risk?

Comment: What would keep it alive at that point? Most browsers run tabs in distinct processes. How would they leak?

Comment: That's what I think, but you never know with Javascript and the browsers. Anyway, it was something that was bugging my mind

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you'll be fine.  The window is a container process for the Javascript, so your handlers are destroyed with the window.

Answer (score 3):

Closing the tab will terminate any listeners running within it.

Comment: If closing the tab will terminate the listeners, then you don't really need to do that by hand, like OP asked, yeah?

Comment: @ssube I was answering yes to ‘Does the browser clear event listeners’ but have removed it as it’s clearly not a question that can have a clear yes or no answer!